# Positioning spheres above an a-element and maintain position when browser resized

Tags: aframe

Using A-FRAME v0.9.0 and I have an a-entity placed which is using an obj-mode and I have positioned spheres to represent buttons that the user can interact with their mouse on top of the a-entity.

When the browser is resized the spheres stay in position yet the a-entity scales in size. The scaling happens when the browser is resized vertically but does nothing when resized horizontally.

My goal is to have the spheres stay positioned within the confines of the a-entity and maintain responsiveness ie: stay in the same place.

I have tried to wrap the spheres with a a-entity and id in order to change the width and height by way of adjusting position and scale programmatically with window resize but the x, y, z coordinates was not successful.

```
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.0/aframe.min.js"></script>


    <a-scene class="fullscreen" id="ascene" 
        inspector=""
        keyboard-shortcuts=""
        screenshot="" 
        vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"
        cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">


    <a-camera active="true" spectator="true"
            wasd-controls="wsEnabled:false;enabled:false"
            look-controls="enabled: false"
            zoom="2.4"
            position="0.3 0.0 -1.8"
            rotation="0.0 132.5 0.0"
            camera="zoom:1.5"
            look-controls=""
            camera="active:true"A
            data-aframe-inspector-original-camera=""
            look-controls="enabled: false"></a-camera>



    <a-entity id="btn_container" position="0 0 0" scale="0.02 0.02 0.02">
        <!-- BOTTOM LEFT -->
        <a-entity id="btn_bl">
            <a-sphere class="msgBtn" 
                    id="geometry_br"
                    data-msg="1"
                    geometry=""
                    sphere="2"
                    position="-0.853 -0.044 -3.116"
                    scale="0.02 0.02 0.02"
                    id="hotspot_tr"
                    material="color: green"
                    opacity="0.80"
                    emissive="green"
                    animation__mouseenter="property: components.material.material.color; type: color; to: blue; startEvents: mouseenter; dur: 200";
                    animation__mouseleave="property: components.material.material.color; type: color; to: green; startEvents: mouseleave; dur: 200";
                    animation__hotspot="property: scale;
                        dur: 500;
                        from: 0.02 0.02 0.02;
                        to: 0 0 0;
                        dir: reverse;
                        easing: easeInQuad;
                        loop: false"          
                    >
            </a-sphere>
            <a-ring  material="color: green"
                position="-0.853 -0.044 -3.116"
                scale="0.045 0.045 0.045"
                radius-inner="0"
                radius-outer="2"
                animation="property: scale;
                elasticity: 400;
                dur: 1000;
                from: 0.035 0.035 0.035;
                to: 0 0 0;
                dir: reverse;
                easing: easeInCubic;
                loop: true;"
                animation__2="property: opacity;
                elasticity: 400;
                dur: 1000;
                from: 0.45;
                to: 0.0;
                dir: reverse;
                easing: easeInQuad;
                loop: true">
            </a-ring>
        </a-entity>

        <!-- CENTER TOP -->
        <a-entity id="btn_ct">
            <a-sphere class="msgBtn" 
                id="geometry_ct"
                data-msg="2"
                geometry=""
                sphere="2"
                position="-0.500 0.111 -2.846"
                scale="0.02 0.02 0.02"
                id="hotspot_ct"
                material="color: green"
                emissive="green"
                animation__mouseenter="property: components.material.material.color; type: color; to: blue; startEvents: mouseenter; dur: 200";
                animation__mouseleave="property: components.material.material.color; type: color; to: green; startEvents: mouseleave; dur: 200";
                animation__hotspot="property: scale;
                dur: 1000;
                from: 0.02 0.02 0.02;
                to: 0 0 0;
                dir: reverse;
                easing: easeInQuad;
                loop: false"          
                    >
            </a-sphere>
            <a-ring  material="color: green"
                position="-0.500 0.111 -2.846"
                scale="0.045 0.045 0.045"
                radius-inner="0"
                radius-outer="2"
                animation="property: scale;
                elasticity: 400;
                dur: 1000;
                from: 0.035 0.035 0.035;
                to: 0 0 0;
                dir: reverse;
                easing: easeInCubic;
                loop: true;"
                animation__2="property: opacity;
                elasticity: 400;
                dur: 1000;
                from: 0.45;
                to: 0.0;
                dir: reverse;
                easing: easeInQuad;
                loop: true">
            </a-ring>
        </a-entity>

        <!-- TOP RIGHT -->
        <a-entity id="btn_tr">
            <a-sphere class="msgBtn" 
                id="hotspot_tr"
                data-msg="3"
                geometry=""
                sphere="2"
                position="0.181 0.464 -3.000"
                scale="0.02 0.02 0.02"
                id="hotspot_bl"
                material="color: green"
                emissive="green"
                animation__mouseenter="property: components.material.material.color; type: color; to: blue; startEvents: mouseenter; dur: 200";
                animation__mouseleave="property: components.material.material.color; type: color; to: green; startEvents: mouseleave; dur: 200";
                animation__hotspot="property: scale;
                dur: 1000;
                from: 0.02 0.02 0.02;
                to: 0 0 0;
                dir: reverse;
                easing: easeInQuad;
                loop: false"          
                >
            </a-sphere>
            <a-ring  material="color: green"
                position="0.181 0.464 -3.000"
                scale="0.045 0.045 0.045"
                radius-inner="0"
                radius-outer="2"
                animation="property: scale;
                elasticity: 400;
                dur: 1000;
                from: 0.035 0.035 0.035;
                to: 0 0 0;
                dir: reverse;
                easing: easeInCubic;
                loop: true;"
                animation__2="property: opacity;
                elasticity: 400;
                dur: 1000;
                from: 0.45;
                to: 0.0;
                dir: reverse;
                easing: easeInQuad;
                loop: true">
            </a-ring>
        </a-entity>
    </a-entity>




    </a-scene>


    <script>
    // CALL RESIZE WHEN SCENE LOADED
    document.querySelector('a-scene').addEventListener('loaded', function () { resize() })

    // CALL RESIZE WHEN WINDOW RESIZED
    window.addEventListener("resize", function() { resize() });
    var acanvas = document.getElementsByClassName("a-canvas")[0];
    var btn_container = document.getElementById("btn_container");
    var btn_container_scale = btn_container.getAttribute("scale");

    function resize() {
        console.log("resize")
        var w = window.innerWidth;
        btn_container_scale.x = w/1000;
        btn_container_scale.y = w/1000;
        btn_container_scale.z = w/1000;
    }

    </script>
```

When the browser is resized the spheres along with the a-entity scale respectively while maintaining their position on top of the a-entity with the obj-model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjusted the the camera's zoom with a function that is called on document load and resize that uses window.matchMedia for the width of the browser then adjusting the camera zoom attribute accordingly in order to keep things in view on smaller viewports.

```
document.querySelector('a-scene').addEventListener('loaded', function () { resize() })


window.addEventListener("resize", function() { resize() });

var camera1 = document.getElementById("camera1");

function resize() {
   camera1.setAttribute("camera","zoom: 3.5")

   if(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1300px)").matches) {
    camera1.setAttribute("camera","zoom: 3.0")
  }
  if(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1100px)").matches) {
      camera1.setAttribute("camera","zoom: 2.5")
  }
  if(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 950px)").matches) {
      camera1.setAttribute("camera","zoom: 2.0")
  }
  if(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 450px)").matches) {
      camera1.setAttribute("camera","zoom: 1.5")
    }
}
```